# Lua script interacting (store/read) with multiple redis instances

Tags: lua, redis

I have a 8 core system. I am running 7 Redis instances on this (so that almost all cores are utilized). I know I can interact with a Redis instance with a Lua script (do client side processing on server). But its just one Lua script interacting with one Redis instance.

Can I make a Lua script to interact (store/read) with all redis instances on a node?

Comment: No. Not with a server-side Lua script. You can still do it with a client-side script though.

Comment: You can still run a Redis client on the server machine. And it can be a Lua script. But you cannot run it in a Redis instance itself.

Comment: I want to do the processing on server, as that way I can send less data to the client (some kind of data filtering). Assuming I use single redis instance on 8 core machine, can I execute lua script (client side processing on redis server) in multi-threaded form i.e. create multiple threads within Lua script and do the processing. I guess this way multiple threads will use all cores but all redis calls they make will get serialized (as redis is single-threaded). But the post processing of records that are read/fetched can be done in parallel.

Comment: No, you cannot. The Lua engine is tied to Redis main thread. You cannot spawn new threads from Lua. Redis data structures are not designed to be accessed by different threads anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In Redis it is not possible. But you can do it in Tarantool, which luckily has the same lua language for server side scripting, so you should not have problems migrating your existing code. Tarantool is pretty much like redis but has some unique features, e.g. it supports rpc calls from a lua script to another instances including local ones. I have not found yet another NoSQL in-memory solution having a feature like this.

Comment: This is interesting!! Is the [shard doc](https://github.com/tarantool/shard) the right place to start a small example of a Tarantool Lua script e.g. selecting data from multiple shards and do something with them? Or are there already code examples to look at?

Comment: You can start from this. Also there a channel where developers are helping community. You can enter there through this link: https://telegram.me/tarantool